# Turn on bluetooth automatically when application is open

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm creating a project which receives data from an arduino device. When I launches the application, it sends a confirmation if I want to Turn On my bluetooth.
My goal is that, when I launches the application, it will automatically turn ON the bluetooth in the device bypassing the confirmation phase. Is this possible???

Comment: If your app goes to the public, it is best not to turn on bluetooth without the user's permission. In any case @ritesh-gune's answer should do the trick

Comment: our project is for the use of visually impaired people so, we need the application to have "less pressing in the screen" operation :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first activity or the base activity you can do as follows:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 

if (! mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBtAdapter.enable(); 
}
```

Provide following permissions in your manifest files.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

**Note:** IMHO it is a good practice to ask user for confirmation before turning the bluetooth on.

Comment: thank you for the info sir. this is what we need in our project :)

Comment: If that is the case, then mark it as answer so that it will be helpful for the future viewers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once the Activity started means, For bluetooth enabling function ,
you can give following code  in onStart or onCreate method

```
BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
if (! mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBtAdapter.enable(); 
}
```

and also add the following permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these below lines in oncreate method,it will turn on the bluetooth once you open the app

BluetoothAdapter BA=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BA.enable();